# How to benchmark apache/nginx setup

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, fastcgi, benchmark

I am planning to setup nginx as reverse proxy. I will have apache to deliver my dynamic content, and nginx will deliver the static content.

My configuration i have now is just Apache with fastCGI. This gives me no configuration problems and runs great.

After I have set up nginx I want to run some benchmarks to see if I really got some performance increases, else i will switch back.

Does anyone know how I can benchmark this type of setup? Or maybe someone did this already and have some canned results, I will be glad to hear them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [siege](http://linux.die.net/man/1/siege) utility... It is a simple command line program for roughly benchmarking a server configuration.

It basically just requests pages from a defined list in an arbitrary parallel fashion and compiles a nice statistic in the end like average response time, how many times the connection timed out, etc...

It is nice to estimate, how many users/traffic your configuration will be able to stand.